# MongoDB Atlas text index with autocomplete failing to match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I created a text index on one of my database collections which has autocomplete set for each. The collection fields which I have indexed are firstname, surname and email. The following is what I used to create my text index. It succeeds:

```
 {
 "mappings": {
"dynamic": false,
"fields": {
  "email": [
    {
      "foldDiacritics": false,
      "maxGrams": 7,
      "minGrams": 3,
      "tokenization": "edgeGram",
      "type": "autocomplete"
    }
  ],
  "firstname": [
    {
      "foldDiacritics": false,
      "maxGrams": 7,
      "minGrams": 3,
      "tokenization": "edgeGram",
      "type": "autocomplete"
    }
  ],
  "surname": [
    {
      "foldDiacritics": false,
      "maxGrams": 7,
      "minGrams": 3,
      "tokenization": "edgeGram",
      "type": "autocomplete"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

When I run the following query in the mongoDB shell I receive no error but also no results when the surname field has an exact match to the query:

```
db.users.aggregate([ { "$search": { "autocomplete": 
{ "query": "janson","path": "surname", "fuzzy": 
{ "maxEdits": 2, "prefixLength": 3 } } } }])
```

I have also tried it with all three collection fields in the index:

```
db.users.aggregate([ { "$search": { "autocomplete": 
{ "query": "janson","path": ["firstname","surname", "email"], "fuzzy": 
{ "maxEdits": 2, "prefixLength": 3 } } } }])
```

This gives me the following error:

> "Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: "path" must be a string (from "autocomplete")",

I don't see how the fault could be with my index definition because it is validated by atlas and exists on the server. What could be the problem?

Thanks

EDIT

a simplified query:

```
db.groups.aggregate([ { "$search": { "autocomplete": { "query": "test", "path": "title" } } }])
```

The Atlas index specification:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "title": [
        {
          "foldDiacritics": false,
          "maxGrams": 7,
          "minGrams": 3,
          "tokenization": "edgeGram",
          "type": "autocomplete"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

A simple document which is purported by Atlas to be 100% indexed:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f773d551dd78dfa97219ae2"
    },
    "title": "test"
}
```

Comment: Works perfect to me. Is your index finished building? It takes some time.

Comment: Yes on atlas it says 100% indexed. I thought it might be a case of previous documents not being indexed so I added another but it still returns nothing. I even removed the fuzzy operator to simplify it but nothing is helping.

Comment: Can you add an example document? Essential fields only please

Comment: Yes I have added the changes to the question

Comment: hmm, still works. Do you reproduce it with the examples you added?

Comment: I think I get it. I was able to reproduce. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify index name if you are using non-default index:

```
db.users.aggregate([ { 
    "$search": {
        "index": "<REPLACE_WITH_INDEX_NAME>", 
        "autocomplete": { 
            "query": "janson",
            "path": "surname", 
            "fuzzy": { 
                "maxEdits": 2, 
                "prefixLength": 3 
            } 
         } 
    } 
}])
```

the `<REPLACE_WITH_INDEX_NAME>` is `SearchIndex1` on the image below:

[image: index name]

Comment: Thank you friend. I created my first index on three text fields but when I specify all three of them in the path I get the error outlined in the question above. Do you know how to get around it?

Comment: Like autocompletion from 3 fields? There is no way. It's not supported. They explicitly highlighted it at https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/#options `The autocomplete operator does not support multi in the field path.`

Comment: Yea I saw that. Why is it possible to successfully add three autocomplete fields to an index if that functionality does not exist, is there perhaps a way to combine the result of three individual searches on each field?

Comment: I guess "Why" is a rhetorical question. Try compound search or facets. It's a pipeline after all.

Comment: It just seemed counter intuitive. Thanks a bunch for the help though.

Comment: The search is Atlas specific offer and unlike Mongo is not open source. I can speculate tho. They built it on top of Lucene after all. My understanding is that "autocomplete"  index is the only option to use ngram tokenizer. So you can specify which fields you want to index and then use **any** of the indexed fields for search. The limitation of a single field is likely due to implementation trade offs. Must be  because the index is rather heavy. Try to talk to Atlas support, may be even file a feature request.